# How to use the rotate operator on Blender Python if you execute the script on the background?

Tags: python, scripting, blender, bpy

I am importing a model that consists of multiple individual meshes. Right after import (where everything is selected), I want to rotate the imported selected objects based on a [X, Y, Z] angle parameter. Also I want to run the script as a blender "--background" shell process.

I tried doing something like this but it doesn't seem to work.

`bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=math.radians(param.x), orient_axis='X');`
`bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=math.radians(param.y), orient_axis='Y');`
`bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=math.radians(param.z), orient_axis='Z');`

I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.transform.rotate.poll() failed, context
> is incorrect

I tried searching the internet for solutions but I couldn't understand exactly what is going wrong. Also I think this error doesn't appear because I am running with "--background", but because I am running it as a terminal command.

Thanks in advance!
I am using Blender 2.9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Im running the same issue. I have some scripts that worked so fine in blender 2.83 as module using bpy.ops.transformm.rotate, now this is not working on the new bpy (blender as module) version 2.93.

I realized that `bpy.ops.transform.rotate.poll()` return false using the module, from python script, while the function `bpy.ops.transform.translate.poll()` returns true.

However when I run the same function in the scripting console of the blender 2.93 GUI, the function `bpy.ops.transform.rotate.poll()` returns true.

So I think is a bug in the new version.

However I was able to fix this passing a VIEW_3D context as first argument in the operator:

```
>>> ov=bpy.context.copy()
>>> ov['area']=[a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type=="VIEW_3D"][0]
>>> bpy.ops.transform.rotate(ov)
{'FINISHED'}
```

In your case:

```
# ... already selected objects, ov is for override, I'm lazy.
>>> ov=bpy.context.copy()
>>> ov['area']=[a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type=="VIEW_3D"][0]
>>> bpy.ops.transform.rotate(ov, value=math.radians(param.x), orient_axis='X')
{'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Man you are great! Helped me a lot, thank you! Have a nice day!

Comment: Ran into the exact same issue. For the record the script was working with Blender 2.90 and stopped working in Blender 2.93 (and also 2.92 - didn't try 2.91).

Comment: I can confirm in 2.91 the original worked. Mine also stopped in 2.93 ( didn't try 2.92). The fix is awesome! I wonder how you figured it out!

Comment: Also, when you said it was a bug, is this what blender.org intended, or is something require a fix from them, and is it already fixed in 3.x? I haven't found a bug report on their site. I haven't tried anything in Blender 3.x - which I will attempt that on my current python workflow after the summer.

Comment: In case you got the deprecation warning: `area = [a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type=="VIEW_3D"][0]` then put your code inside `with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):`